# Modify a variable in C++ program with the android UI in openframeworks?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, openframeworks

I'm developing an application with openframeworks, for android.
I wish to use the android UI for navigation in my app. 
But I am blocked at the point how to communicate my interaction with the android ui in my openframeworks' code.
I read a lot about JNI, but as far I understand it allows to use C++ code from Java, but I don't find how to make it interact with the rest of my code. 
When I write my JNI/C++ function, I need to call it into that:

```
extern "C" {
    ...
}
```

But I'm unable to modify any variable of my openframeworks program.
How can I do for by example get a boolean or a int from the android UI into openframeworks?
Maybe I am asking something impossible or I am missing a point?

Comment: this could be a dumb suggestion. I had integrated linephone android in my project ,when ever i change the c code i had to rebuild it .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i seek a way for communicate between the java code of my app and the c++ code, as now i have no issue about compiling.

Answer (score 1):

You would use JNI to establish communication between c++ and java. 
The UI part should be done in Java. Notice you have a srcJava folder and a res/layout folder.
If you have the ADT eclipse add-on you should be able to add a simple button in main_layout.xml. Try something like:

```
<cc.openframeworks.OFGLSurfaceView android:id="@+id/of_gl_surface"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <!-- add here other views' layouts -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="?buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/myButton"
                style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Bam!" />
            <!-- the text should move to a string in the values.xml -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in OFActivity.java try something like this:

```
package cc.openframeworks.androidGuiExample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import cc.openframeworks.OFAndroid;


public class OFActivity extends cc.openframeworks.OFActivity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String packageName = getPackageName();

        ofApp = new OFAndroid(packageName,this);

        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);//id from layout xml
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ofApp.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ofApp.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (OFAndroid.keyDown(keyCode, event)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (OFAndroid.keyUp(keyCode, event)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
    }


    OFAndroid ofApp;



    // Menus
    // http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Create settings menu options from here, one by one or infalting an xml
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // This passes the menu option string to OF
        // you can add additional behavior from java modifying this method
        // but keep the call to OFAndroid so OF is notified of menu events
        if(OFAndroid.menuItemSelected(item.getItemId())){

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        // This method is called every time the menu is opened
        //  you can add or remove menu options from here
        return  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```

You're mainly after the last lines in `onCreate`:

- you use findViewById to access a component from the layout xml
- you set a listener for events - different components have different listeners to implement. Usually it's a good idea to have the ui stuff(GUI thread) disconnected from the rest of the processing done to avoid freezes.